# Save doc file as pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf, python-docx

I want to save a doc file as pdf using python, I tried so many solution but I couldn't find the right one.

This is my code, I tried to make the output file as a pdf file but it didn't open. Any help is highly appreciated :

```
def replace_string(filenameInput, filenameOutput):  

    doc = Document(filenameInput)

    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        for d in J['data']:
            if p.text.find(d['variable']) >= 0:
                p.text = p.text.replace(d['variable'], d['value'])
    
    doc.save(filenameOutput)

replace_string('test.docx', 'test2.pdf')
```

Comment: You can't convert one binary file format to another simply by changing the extension. PDF is a print format (a file containing Postscript printer commands), not an editable document. Word's `Save as PDF` essentially *prints* the document's contents into a PDF file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import docx2pdf
def convert_file(filenameInput, filenameOutput):
    docx2pdf.convert(filenameInput, filenameOutput)

convert_file('test.docx', 'test2.pdf')
```

There is a Python package called docx2pdf. You can use it to simply convert docx file into pdf!

There is a link to the package! https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/

Comment: There's nothing "simply" about this module. It actually uses Word to load the document and then calls Word's `Save as PDF` command to save the document as a PDF. This means you actually have to buy Word